# Is there a website for figuring out who secret carriers / super saver fares are with?

Tags: online-resources, airlines, terminology, travel-tools

I've seen both on onetravel and kayak now, where it describes flights as:

"Secret Carrier"

or "Super saver fare"

eg:

[image]

Seven months ago, [I asked on this site what that meant](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7943/101), as it was new to me.  Now I'm used to knowing, and then got asked what a certain secret carrier was.

After a bit of sleuthing, I was able to work out, for example, which flight left Rome for Warsaw at a particular time, and that was fine.  However, it involved some googling and looking up schedules.

Is there a site that you could just give it two airports and one of the dep/arr times and have it tell you the airline?

I admit it's not a terribly complex thing to look for, but if such a site existed, it'd save me some time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed you can. [Once](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/751/108) [again](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5558/108) it's the Swiss Army knife of airline search engines [matrix.itasoftware.com](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) that comes to your rescue.

[image: Matrix ITA Software time-restricted search]

While it won't allow you to restrict searches to a *specific* time, it does allow you to choose specific *time windows*, which in most cases if you order according in ascending/descending order on the results page will allow you to quickly narrow down the flight that is being offered as a 'secret carrier'.

Comment: Hmm, that's not bad, although I suspect googling the time (eg 0825) is probably faster in some cases, than searching through the results.  Will have to give it a try next time tho and see :)