# 72h China transit visa: Which airlines offer interlining in Beijing?

Tags: visas, airlines, china, bookings, terminology

I would like to take advantage of the [72h China transit visa](http://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-72hour/) at Beijing Capital airport and city.

My confusion concerns the term "interline ticket" in the regulations. To me, that sounds like I have to book the flight into and out of Beijing at one airline carrier on the same booking reference - which according to my attempts is not to easy, especially since China Eastern doesn't offer multi-city bookings (at least online).

Is my interpretation correct? If so, which carriers are the usual suspects to offer bookings for this (eg. HKG-PEK, PEK-ICN)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably having trouble booking a connection through Beijing on China Eastern because they're based in Shanghai!

Instead, try [Air China](http://www.airchina.com.au/en/index.html)'s online booking site: if you select origin and destination to be any cities outside China, it will offer you connections via Beijing.

If you want more creative options, see [this question about finding flight connections with stopovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/modifying-online-flights-to-include-stopovers) (TL;DR: Use ITA Matrix) and [this for going about booking them](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21671/how-can-i-book-a-flight-plan-found-on-matrix-airfare-search) (print out fare construction and go to an agent).  Trying `HKG X:PEK ICN` for a random date in June, I get options on Air China, China Southern, AC+Asiana, Cathay+Korean, etc.  Obviously the single-airline options will have the best prices though.

Comment: Okay, so far for the finding. Sadly, I couldn't find a longer layover than 25 hours. And one should still be careful to assure that you need that seat number on the outbound ticket already upon arrival in Beijing