# USA to Vietnam and Taiwan, what "route" of plane tickets should I take?

Tags: air-travel, usa, tickets, vietnam, taiwan

I am scoping out a motorcycle trip in November with two friends. They are planning separate post-trip travels in December than myself, but we will be spending the majority of November biking around Vietnam.

Roundtrip tickets from Houston to Vietnam are in the 700 dollar range from skyscanner, however, I have many friends in Taiwan and would like to spend some time there as well.

Considering that it's usually cheapest to get round trip tickets, should I get a round trip ticket for Taiwan for November returning late December, then while in Taiwan get round trip tickets for Vietnam shortly after my arrival, then returning to Taiwan before my flight back to HOU? Or is there some option I am not aware of?

I am a US Citizen.

Comment: If you buy tickets in that manner, remember that you will have to transit landside in order to transfer your checked luggage, and as a result, you might need additional visas.

Comment: US citizens do not need visas for Taiwan.

Comment: Try HOU to SGN via TPE on EVA Airlines.

Comment: @jpatokal True, but nowhere in this question is any traveler's nationality mentioned.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Sphero do you know of a better way of finding the cheapest days on Eva other than trying random ones on their website?

Comment: I do not, but there are many experts here. Obviously around Christmas and American Thanksgiving and New Years (and spring break if you go out that far) will tend to be pricier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your cheapest option would be to **find a round-trip that goes to Vietnam via Taiwan**, which will be priced competitively with other US-Vietnam flights, then **add a stopover** in Taiwan on way over, which would typically cost around $100 extra (YMMV).

Your two options for this would be Taiwanese carrier China Airlines and EVA Air, or if you flip the itinerary and stop over in Vietnam, Vietnam Airlines.

As tickets like this are difficult to impossible to book online, I would recommend [exploring your options with ITA Matrix](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/modifying-online-flights-to-include-stopovers/5558#5558) and then using a bricks'n'mortar travel agent to do the actual booking.

Answer (score 1):

Use the multi city feature on your preferred booking engine to see if you can construct an itinerary stopping in several cities at a reasonable price.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to explore.

You can look at round trips from Houston to both Vietnam and Taiwan and the costs for round trip between Vietnam & Taiwan.  And you need to look at these flights separately, as the inter-Asia prices can vary depending on your starting gateway.

You can price out an open jaw ticket (fly to one city and return from another), then look at the cost of a one way Inter-asia ticket to connect the two.  Again you need to look at both directions.

Finally you can book a multi-city itinerary going from Houston to Vietnam to Taiwan to Houston (or vice versa).

While the rule of thumb is that a single round trip is cheaper, that is not always the case.  You can find excellent open jaw and multi-city deals, it all depends on the dates and what seats are available on the flights.

Comment: The only option for an open-jaw originating from the US would be United, since no other American carrier serves both Vietnam and Taiwan.  However, a round-trip with stopover would be possible on China Airlines, EVA and Vietnam Airlines.

Comment: @jpatokal - Delta offers flights to both (code share but nonetheless eligible for open jaw fares). And other carriers serve both from the US via various gateways.

Comment: What's the difference between open jaw and round trip with stopover?

Comment: An open jaw is A-B, C-A, and you need to sort out your own flight from B to C.  A roundtrip with stopover(s) is A-B-C-B-A.