# Are there any sites that let me book 7 or more multi-city flights?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, bookings

I have a project that is requiring me to travel to seven different locations and I need to find a travel site that will allow me to book more than six multi-flights in order to accommodate for this need. does anyone know of any sites that will allow me to do this?

Comment: I don't know any systems that support such an extensive multi-location flight. I've experience that sometimes it's already a lot more difficult to book a flight consisting of four legs than to book 2x2 legs individually. Is there a reason you cannot split your six stops?

Comment: Why not split this in 2x4 legs?

Comment: what about a round-the-world ticket? It might not be the best fit for your specific case (there usually are some conditions like always go eastwards) but it's worth trying: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-should-i-know-about-around-the-world-flights

Answer (score 6):

The only time I have done 19 stops is with a traditional travel agent but you can do this with [Air Treks](http://www.airtreks.com/) and they do have really good multi-city prices. It took several days to get it all but the agents did most of the work and I got a folder with 39 boarding passes several weeks later.

Traditional sites like Expedia, Travelocity, etc are extremely expensive for multi-city routes, at least every single time I tried! They even have a shorter limit which may be fewer than 7 stops.

Now you did not say where you are going - which is great to keep the question general - but you may try some variants if you visiting both cities which are close together and some that are far.

For example, you can get a price for a route that goes through major cities and then take short round-trip domestic flights on local airlines to reach the smaller cities. Otherwise you may end up with excessive costs or really strange itineraries like getting a stop over in China between two cities in the Philipines which happened to me!

Another option to save costs is to build your trip out of enclosed round trips. For example if you want to go A -> B -> C -> A, you can A -> B -> C -> B -> A by booking A <-> B and B <-> C as two round trips. I saved over $1K like this once.

Comment: How do you get 39 boarding passes for 19 flights?

Comment: There were 19 stops on my itinerary. The other 20 passes were for connections, all but one segment passed through a single hub city (Hong Kong mostly - got to know the airport quite well!) and the last segment had two stops.

Answer (score 1):

**Kiwi** supports 8 segments in multi city flight search

[image: kiwi]

**AirWander** supports upto 16 segments in multi city flight search

[image: airwander]

see: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/152708/40874 for more detail