# Flight search for multi-stop with 10 segments

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, bookings, flight-search-engines

There is a similar question on this site, [Are there any sites that let me book 7 or more multi-city flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14904/are-there-any-sites-that-let-me-book-7-or-more-multi-city-flights).

But, it's from 2013. And lists just one site - **https://airtreks.com**, that gives an estimate.
For example:
1. https://tripplanner.airtreks.com/estimate/934439
2. https://tripplanner.airtreks.com/estimate/934441
3. https://tripplanner.airtreks.com/estimate/934450
4. https://tripplanner.airtreks.com/estimate/934452

We're in 2020 now. In the last 7 years, i am sure some improvements must have been made in this regard. At least, i have hope.

I checked itamatrix, google flights and skyscanner.

[image: google flights]

[image: skyscanner]

[image: matrix]

Comment: The fact that another question/answer is old isn't a reason to re-post the exact same question.  If you have an updated answer (which appears to be at least part the reason you opened this question), then please post it on the previous question.

Comment: Hi @Doc, i have added an updated answer to the old question too, i made a new question because my trip required 10+ segments and the other question talked about 7+. You may delete/close/archive this question.

Answer (score 3):

**Kiwi** supports upto 8 segments for multi city flight search

**AirWander** (**https://airwander.com**) has the option for multi city flight search upto **16 segments**,

screenshots for example,

[image: 10 segments]

[image: results]

[image: flight details]

At the moment, flight search engines and maximum number of segments for multi-city search can be summarised as follows:

1. Expedia : 5
2. Kayak : 6
3. Google Flights: 5
4. ITA Matrix : 6
5. Kiwi : 8
6. AirWander : 16

Answer (score 2):

Kiwi and Airwander have expertise in multi-stop as does ITA matrix if you know how to use it.

Airtreks can do up to 25 stops.

Indie can do 25 stops as well:

I help build these 2 products over the years to be clear.

Cheers to all.